# NoSQL: indexing and keyword-based searching

Tags: mongodb, indexing, couchdb, full-text-indexing, nosql

I have an application that stores items (e.g. web documents). Each item can feature a arbitrary large set of tags. And typical a common query is to retrieve all documents with given set of tags. Well, a pretty common Web application.

Now I'm thinking about a NoSQL database as persistent storage. Various NoSQL systems (e.g. MongoDB) support secondary indexes and with that keyword-based searches. Examples showing how to do it in different systems are easy to find. The problem is, I would like to know what's going on "under the hood", i.e. how/where the secondary indexes stored, and how a query with a list of tags is actually executed. Particularly in systems with many nodes.

I'm aware of solutions based on Map/Reduce or similar. But here I'm interested how the indexing works. Questions I have, for example, are:

- Does the secondary index only store the item/object id or more?
- If a query contains k tags, are k subqueries - one for each tag - executed and the k partial results are combined one the initiating node?

Where can I find such information for different NoSQL systems? Thanks a lot for any hints.

Christian

Answer (score 2):

In MongoDB an index on tags would be done by utilizing the multi-keys feature whereby the database tries to match documents against each element of an array. You would index this tags attribute of a given document which would create a btree that is constructed out of ranges of tags in that array.

You can learn more about multikeys [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) and can get more information about indexing in MongoDB by watching this presentation: [MongoDB Internals](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosp-2011/mongodb-internals)

**Does the secondary index only store the item/object id or more?**

The indexes consist of the indexed field (lets say it's a tags array in your case, then the field would be a single tag) and an offset used to efficiently locate the document in memory. It also has some padding + other overhead as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607637/are-there-any-tools-to-estimate-index-size-in-mongodb/8610565#8610565)

**If a query contains k tags, are k subqueries - one for each tag - executed and the k partial results are combined one the initiating node?**

It depends, but if, for example, the query were using an $or on the tag field I think the queries are performed in parallel, each in O(log n) time, and the results are combined to form the result set but I'm not sure about this though.

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for your reply and the links. The presentation was indeed quite interesting, maybe a bit too internal :). What I found out by now is that (at least) MongoDB applies a document-based partitioning for the index, i.e. each node/shard/? has maintains it's own local index. A multiterm query is then sent to all(?) nodes and processed locally. (The alternative method described in my 2nd question rather applies to global index, i.e. term-based partitioning of the index). Thanks again for your help, Christian