# What are the things to consider while assessing the hardware (RAM and hard disk) for mongodb and how to assess them?

Tags: mongodb

We are going to use mongodb for an automated alert notification system. This will also notify different server statistics and business statistics. We would like to have a separate server for this and need to assess the hard ware(both RAM, hard disc and other configurations if any)

Shall some one shed some light on these plases....

What are the things to consider...?

How to prceeed once we collect that information(Is there any standard)...?

Currently I have only the below information.

Writes per second:  400

Average record size in the write: 5KB

Data retendancy policy: 30days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb buffers writes in memory and flushes them to disk once a while (60sec by default, can be configured with `--syncdelay`), so writing 400 5KB docs per sec is not going to be a problem if mongo can quickly update all indices (it would be helpful if you could give some info on the type and number of indices you're going to have).

You're going to have 1'036'800'000 documents / 5TB of raw data each month. Mongo will need more than 5TB to store that (for each doc it will repeat all key names, plus indices). To [estimate index size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607637/are-there-any-tools-to-estimate-index-size-in-mongodb):

```
2 * [ n * ( 18 bytes overhead + avg size of indexed field + 5 or so bytes of conversion fudge factor ) ]
```

Where n is the number of documents you have.

And then you can estimate the amount of RAM (you need to fit your indices there if you care about query performance).