# MongoDB _id index doesn't scale linearly

Tags: mongodb, database-indexes, mongodb-indexes

I have a collection with 1.5B documents and the _id index is roughly 75Gb. I'm wondering why the _id index is so large because I have another collection in the same database with 100M documents and the _id index is only 2.8Gb. It seems odd to me that the index size is not proportionally larger.

Comment: Do both collections have the same type for the _id field?

Comment: they are both the standard _id field.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607637/are-there-any-tools-to-estimate-index-size-in-mongodb

Comment: @dnickless I would think that things have changed quite a lot in the last 7 years. That answer is pretty old

Comment: Hmm, the concept of B-Trees certainly hasn't changed in the last 7 years and this is what MongoDB still uses... Also see this post which is a little bit newer: http://zhangliyong.github.io/posts/2014/02/19/mongodb-index-internals.html and you might also want to experiment with this thing here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/#dbcmd.compact